# PYTHON BaseHTTPServer + UWSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi

Подскажи пожалуйста в каком виде  я должен отдавать статус сервера и тело ответа от своего приложения в uwsgi для корректной работы ?

```
import BaseHTTPServer

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):


    def do_GET(self):
        AppLogic = AppLogic()
        (status, response) = AppLogic.Query_get(*args)
        self.send_response(status)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response)
        self.wfile.flush()

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.headers.getheader('content-length'):
            length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
            postData = self.rfile.read(length)
            AppLogic = AppLogic()
            (status, response) = AppLogic.Query_post(*args)
            self.send_response(status)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(response)
            self.wfile.flush()

def test(Handler=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler,
         Server=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    httpd = Server(('localhost', 8000), Handler)

    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        httpd.server_close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: А где тут uWSGI?

Comment: его тут и нет, хотел по советоваться с людьми кто хорошо знаешь принцип работы uwsgi и подкажет как правильно перенести мое app без лишних танцев с бубном

Comment: Тебе надо написать функцию вида `def myapp(environ, start_response): ...`, которая в зависимости от того, что стоит в `environ` (распарсенный запрос) передаст статус код и опционально заголовки вызовом функции `start_response` и вернет тело ответа. Подробности в любом туториале по WSGI, к примеру [тут](http://wsgi.tutorial.codepoint.net/).